# Easily keep track of physical items within apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, barcode, qr-code, inventory

I am currently in development of an app that keeps track of physical inventory. I am wondering if there is some way that I could possibly use QR Codes or some kind of barcode to scan an item and then have the app recognize the item and pull up the info for the item quickly and efficiently. If anyone has a better or more ideas to solve this then please by all means pitch in I am trying to make a better/easier UI for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options here:
iPhone 3GS/4, iPod touch -> Linea Barcode Scanner(they have their own SDK) by Infinite Peripherals that has magnetic card reader as well. Apple uses these external Accessory for iPod touches in their stores, if you happen to go to Apple Store you can see these their associates carry them. Very reliable option. Costs about $300 ~ 500 a piece.(Nordstorm, Sears, Kmart use them as well).
Verifone sells similar accessory but they aren't as popular as Infinite Peripheral barcode scanners.

Or Reading QR/Barcode using camera is really simple and fast. You can either use ZXing,Zbar sdk to scan barcode and based upon successful scan you can lookup inventory if you have a webservice available. These are free SDK's. Zbar is really fast, I would recommend using Zbar. You have some paid barcode scanners using camera as well like RedLaser.

To manage inventory have your webservices ready, you need to pull information like description, price about item and display in tableview cell. Better UI depends on your requirements and what kind of data you want to show. What you want to do with inventory. So many questions before I can jump to conclusion that this UI looks better.

You can look at shopsavvy api that pulls up item information based on barcode from their database. Paid service though.

Comment: I am looking to save my end users some $$ so I am planning on going with the QR Reader option. Is there a way to link a QR Code with a local database if I am not utilizing a webservice?

Comment: Why Specifically QR Code, Why not Barcode? How do you plan to communicate from iPhone to local database ?

Comment: Basically all of the data is stored on the phone using Core Data. I'm basically trying to allow the user to print off (some kind of) barcodes for each item and when a barcode is scanned from within the app the app responds by going to the item itself to allow editing (of amounts or properties and such). I was thinking we codes because they seem to be the easiest and fastest using an iPhone camera.

Comment: Sure. I have some experience writing similar apps. Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck.

Comment: How would I get it to inform me of which item to open?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3464/discussion-between-0x8badf00d-and-jaba)